# How cairngorm framework works internally

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, cairngorm

I had gone through many documents, no where mentioned how cairngorm framework works internally, means, how cairngorm Event, frontController, BusinessDelegate,ServiceLocator,Commands works and why we are extending or implementing cairngorm class like ICommand, IResponder and cairngormEvent.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the love of GOD, don't use Cairngorm (2) as a framework.  Use either [RobotLegs](http://robotlegs.org/) or [Parsley](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/download.php).  Both of which has awesome documentation and a very active community.

Comment: Cairngorm 3 is based on Parsley.  The modern frameworks work by watching the display list for Views that you're interested in to be added to the stage, then supplying them with dependencies according to rules you set up.  Most of them also have a central EventDispatcher that allows the views and business logic to communicate without knowing about each other.

Comment: Cairngorm 3 isn't based on Parsley.  It's extensions for Parsley.